# How to setup docker machine with Hyper V Internal switch?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I've been practicing docker and docker-swarm for quite sometime.   I had created docker-machine's (manager, worker1 and worker2 nodes) using virtualbox and was able to complete the orchestration

Now, I am trying to repeat the same using Hyper-V (using internal v-switch) in my office, but it hung with the following

```
ERROR:  Waiting for the host
```

My office desktop has got only one NIC,   If I create 'external vswitch' and share it using 'network adapter sharing' I lose connectivity to all my office / client related applications

Hence I chose to create hyper-v 'manager' node using 'internal switch'.  I also tried setting up MAT and provided IP address to 'internal switch'.  But NOTHING worked

Should I need / create a hyper-v external switch  prior creating Internal switch ?  Or am I doing something wrong  with internal switch setup?

Comment: Go through this https://dev.to/bitsmonkey/setting-up-docker-with-hyper-v-4936 link

Comment: @PrathameshDoke I already gone through that link.  However, it uses External Switch.  However, I want to create docker-machines only with 'Internal Switches'